# Installing R package - can't find required files in PATH

Tags: r, path, gtk, rattle

I'm trying to install the Rattle GUI for R on OS Sierra. Installation requires the RGtk2 package, which prompts me to install GTK+, which it automatically does for me. Despite installing, when I try to load Rattle (or RGtk2) I receive this error:

`Error in as.GType(type) : Cannot convert RGtkBuilder to GType`

From some other Googling, it seems R can't locate the installed files. Another error I get is:

`2: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libSM.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so
  Reason: image not found`

When I head into Library/Frameworks, I see that all these files are installed in the correct locations, including the GTK+ framework. The one that puzzles me is `/opt/X11/lib/libSM.6.dylib`, I'm not sure where that would be located.

Does anyone have any idea why R won't recognize GTK+? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you're missing X window. Have you installed Xquartz (https://www.xquartz.org/) ?

Comment: I did not, I just assumed all the dependencies would have been installed for me. I'll give that a shot, thanks!

Which line tells me I'm missing Xquartz?

Comment: I am not sure that will solve your problem but "R_X11.so Reason: image not found" suggests R searches X (xquartz is not part of R, that's why it is not installed by `install.packages()`

Comment: It worked, thanks man! If you wanna post as a full response I can accept your answer. Interestingly enough though, that `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so` already existed, I guess it just can't be properly accessed without Xquartz?